# Will a Xen Server v5.5 Snaphot run on Xen Server v7.0

Tags: xenserver, snapshot, upgrade

I have a Citrix Xen Server version 5.5 running with a few VM's. I want to upgrade the hardware (new hard disks) and also upgrade the OS to the new Citrix Xen Server v7.0.

Can I just make a snaphot of my VM's on version 5.5 and then run them again on version 7.0? There will be no compatibility issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a upgrade in the past and if Xen7 is compatible with your hardware you simply update over your old install. The datastore will be re-detected. (if you have a datastore separated from the Xen OS).

The VM will ask to update the xentool after.

In your case you need a **three step upgrade**, see that chart;

Version Direct upgrade to XenServer 7.0?
XenServer 6.5.0 Yes
XenServer 6.2.0 Yes
XenServer 6.1.0 Yes
XenServer 6.0.2 Yes
XenServer 6.0 Yes
XenServer 5.6, 5.6 Feature Pack 1,
5.6 Service Pack 2
No. You must first upgrade to XenServer 6.2.0, and then to version 7.0
**XenServer 5.5 No. You must first upgrade to XenServer 5.6 (or 5.6 Feature Pack 1, or
5.6 Service Pack 2), and then to 6.2.0, and finally to version 7.0.**
XenServer 5.0.0 No. You must first upgrade to XenServer 5.5, then to 5.6 (or to 5.6
Feature Pack 1 or 5.6 Service Pack 2), then to 6.2.0, and finally to version
7.0

From ; http://docs.citrix.com/content/dam/docs/en-us/xenserver/xenserver-7-0/downloads/xenserver-7-0-installation-guide.pdf

*Be sure to have good backup in case something happen.*